# Getting Segmentation Fault while Inserting Elements in 2d Vector in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, visual-c++, c++14

**I am writing a program in which I sum all of the elements in a 2d vector and find out whether the sum of them is 0 or not.**

**Getting Error which I mentioned above in the title as well as in online editor I am getting *error - Segmentation Fault***

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    vector<vector<int>> arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }   
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            ans = ans + arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    if (ans == 0)
        cout << "YES";
    else
        cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless your vectors are sized beforehand at initialization, you'll need to use `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` to add elements to your vectors.

Comment: Yes, but how to add elements in 2d vector using push_back(). I searched on the internet but didn't got answer. Really appreciate for for your help.@πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: Same way you're adding other new elements of `T` to any `std::vector<T>`, just that the new element `T` added needs to be a `std::vector<int>` in your case. Nothing very special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //User Input
    int num {};
    cout << "Enter a Number: ";
    cin >> num;

    //Init Vector
    vector <int> V1;
    vector <int> V2;
    vector<vector<int>> V2D;

    //Instead of std:cin we use push back;
    for (int i {}; i < num; i++){ 
        V1.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int j {}; j < num; j++){
        V2.push_back(j);
    }

    //Now we combine the Vectors to a 2D Vector
    V2D.push_back(V1);
    V2D.push_back(V2);

    //Display Vector
    //The First Vector is .at(0) and cycles through with each iteration
    for(int i {};i<V2D.at(0).size();i++){
        cout << V2D.at(0).at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    //The Second Vector is .at(1) and gets Cycled through
    for(int j {};j<V2D.at(1).size();j++){
            cout << V2D.at(1).at(j) << " ";
        }

    //The more Vectors you add, the higher the first .at Position gets
    
    //You can mess around with my code and try to implement your idea if you like
    //if (ans == 0)
        //cout << "YES";
    //else
        //cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

You dont have to use a total of 3 Vectors, but I find it easier to explain it like that.

Answer (score 2):

to display something in a vector, use .at()

to make a 2d vector you have to combine 2 vectors:

vector2d.push_back(vector1)

vector2d.push_back(vector2)

now you have a 2D vector.

to add something you use push_back on vector 1 or vector 2.

to display something or use a value in the 2D vector you use vector2d.at().at()

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
 { 

  for (int j = i; j < num; j++)
  {

   cin >> arr.at(i).at(j);

  } 

 }`

i used .at() but still it gives me exception - "out_of_range at Memory Location" @Seaweed1603

Comment: That means you are trying to access a .at position that doesnt exist. Try changing the For loop. I will get back to you when I am home, my battery is running low. 2h max